# Parsing JSON in Android not retrieving all JSON array

Tags: android, android-json

in Android while parsing JSON, it parse only 10 items of JSON array. for example
http://www.example.com/recent_summary/?count=20 
it doesnot matter if i decrease the count to 5 it still return 10 items. but, when i browse the URL in browner. it return all 20 items ... Please help me out.

```
public class MainListActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    protected  String TAG =  MainListActivity.class.getSimpleName(); 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_list);

        if(isNetworkAvailable()) {
            GetPostsTask getPostsTask = new GetPostsTask();
            getPostsTask.execute();

      }else
      {
          Toast.makeText(this,"No Network", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

}

private boolean isNetworkAvailable(){
    ConnectivityManager manager =(ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isAvailable = false ;
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()){
        isAvailable = true ;
        }
    return isAvailable;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_list, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private class GetPostsTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String>{


    protected  String doInBackground(Object...arg){
            JSONObject jsonResponse ;
        try{
            URL url = new URL(http://www.example.com/recent_summary/?count=20 );
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            Log.i("Response Code", ""+responseCode);

            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(reader);
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line ;
            while((line=r.readLine()) != null){
                buffer.append(line + "\n");

            }

           Log.i("ResponseData" , ""+buffer);

            jsonResponse = new JSONObject(buffer.toString());
            JSONArray jsonPosts = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("posts") ;

            for(int i =0 ; i<jsonPosts.length() ; i++){
                JSONObject jsonPost = jsonPosts.getJSONObject(i);
                String title = jsonPost.getString("title");
                Log.i("Post"+i, title);

            }



        }catch (MalformedURLException ex){
            Log.i(TAG , "Error Found ", ex);
        }catch(IOException ex){
            Log.i(TAG , "Error Found ", ex);
        }catch (Exception ex){
            Log.i(TAG , "Error Found ", ex);
        }

        return null ;
    }



  }
}
```

Comment: basic debugging: spit out the value of `jsonPosts.length()`, spit out the contents of `buffer` so you can see the raw json you've received

Comment: jsonPosts.length() retruning 10 items although i made the count = 5

Comment: **Please help me out**

Comment: so did you look at the raw json text? maybe the server-side script is ignoring your limit and sending out 10 no matter what.

Comment: Yep i did check raw json .. First no matter what i'm requesting 5 or 20 items and i'm getting 10 items in my logcat (**Log.i("Post"+i, title)**)  . secondly if server-side had some problem it will be returning 10 items in browser too no matter how much i ask for .. don't u think ?

Comment: if the server's sending out 10 items no matter what, then you should start looking at why it's doing so.

Comment: @marcB .. after **url.openConnection()** my query string change to null.